# Audio from apple tv to google home out of sync

Tags: audio, bluetooth, appletv

I have connected my google home mini via Bluetooth to my Apple TV so I can stream the audio to the google home mini.

The problem is, that the audio is out of sync (~50ms).

I have tried to use the *Wireless Audio Sync* function on Apple TV under settings -> Video and Audio, but that doesn't work as the audio is per default played through the speaker of my TV (and not via Bluetooth).

> The tone will always play from your TV speakers even if you set your audio output to AirPlay.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210526